# pip install throws a Value Error

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am running Python(x,y) 2.7.10.0 on Windows 8.1 64 bit OS. I have used pip before to install some packages but now when I try

```
pip install nltk
pip install pycallgraph
pip search nltk
pip install selenium
```

I get the following error

```
    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy>pip search nltk
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 5, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2880, in <module>
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 432, in _build_master
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 741, in require
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 586, in resolve
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2714, in parse_requirements
      File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2690, in scan_list
    ValueError: ("Expected ',' or end-of-list in", 'pip==7.0.3+xy.11', 'at', '+xy.11')
```

Comment: Can you try printing out `pip --version`? Maybe pip version is too old and you might need to update it by doing `pip install pip --upgrade`. But well, you have `pip 7.0.3` which is relatively new.

Comment: I tried printing out `pip --version` and it throws the same error. It got installed with Python(x,y)'s current release so I am positive its up to date.

Comment: This error doesn't come from pip, but from the underlying pkg_resources package. I'm having a similar problem on a system that just uses pkg_resources (pip isn't even installed on the target system).

Comment: Did you guys ever sort this out? I'm having this problem and can't seem to do anything with pip including `pip --version`

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on windows as well. I got this error no matter what I tried to do with pip. Solution was:

`python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`

I found it on the install-pip instructions page: https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and upgraded to 9.0.1 and works like a charm!.